# Dynamic text area using javascript and forms

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to incorporate a bunch of form text inputs, and use the input from the forms to update a text area below the forms. The text area will be a chunk of HTML code to embed into the signature of an email.

For example, a user would enter their name and details into the forms, and after clicking a submit button, the page will generate a piece of HTML code for them to use in their email signature.

For the form I might have something like:

```
<label for="EmployeeName">Full name:</label>
<input id="EmployeeName" type="text" maxlength="30" size="20"/>
```

But I'm not sure how to use the values from the form to update a text field below. I've spent a good chunk of today trying to research this topic, but can't seem to turn anything up. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, a library may be nice.  I personally recommend Knockout, but everyone has their preferences.  This is how I would do it (not necessarily the best way for you).

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u32zz/)

Your HTML is pretty much the same, just with an added template.  The main difference is the `data-bind` attributes, which tell the elements what data to show.  The `valueUpdate` key, says to update the variable after `keydown`, rather than `blur` (oposite of `focus`).

```
<div>
<label for="EmployeeName">Full name:</label>
<input id="EmployeeName" type="text" maxlength="30" size="20" 
    data-bind="value: EmployeeName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
<label for="XYZ">A Label:</label>
<input id="XYZ" type="text" maxlength="30" size="20" 
    data-bind="value: XYZ, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
</div>

<textarea disabled rows=20 data-bind="value: Email"></textarea>

<script type="text/html" id="signatureTemplate">
<h2>EmployeeName</h2>
<h2>XYZ</h2>
<h3>Company</h3>
<h3>My Position</h3>
</script>
```

Those `data-bind` values match up with your JavaScript, and are updated every time the user types a character.  You can learn Knockout on their [webiste](http://knockoutjs.com/), or just modify this code as needed.

```
var SignatureGenerator = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.EmployeeName = ko.observable('');
    self.XYZ = ko.observable('');

    self.Email = ko.computed(function(){
        return document.getElementById("signatureTemplate").innerHTML
        .replace("EmployeeName", self.EmployeeName());
        .replace("XYZ", self.XYZ());
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(window.app = new SignatureGenerator());
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. I will have to check out Knockout, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: One more quick question, the above works for one input, but how would you add additional inputs/forms? I have tried duplicating the ko.observable variable and the self.Email function, but with no luck. If I create a separate function, how would you add this to the text area?

Comment: I updated the code to also have an XYZ variable.  Find it and, replace it with whatever you want.  It appears in 4 places.  The HTML, **bound to an input**; the **template**, as raw text (in my oversimplistic templating language, as opposed to [this](http://underscorejs.org/#template) or [this](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl)); and in the **Email** function.  Lastly the **ViewModel** as an observable.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but this still isn't working. Have you tried running the new code? For whatever reason with a second variable, the function doesn't seem to run.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but this could be a solution:

```
$('#done').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tag = "<p>";
    var split = tag.substring(1);
    $('#res').val(tag+$('#EmployeeName').val()+'</'+split);
});
```

Where the HTML:

```
<label for="EmployeeName">Full name:</label>
<input id="EmployeeName" type="text" maxlength="30" size="20"/>
<button id="done">Done</button>
<textarea id="res"></textarea>
```

Check it out here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nd87/YaKzS/)

The code basically is saying:

- `$('#done').click` on click of the button
- `e.preventDefault();` don't do the usual action of sending the form but do what I say.
- `var tag = "<p>"` chooses the tag you want to add (paragraph)
- `var split = tag.substring(1);` removes the first `<` so we can later add a slash
- `$('#res').val(` gives the value to the id res of what is in the parenthesis wichi is the tag, the input the `</` and the split: `tag+$('#EmployeeName').val()+'</'+split`

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if I understand the question, but this is what I came up with (using jQuery):

```
// when the go button is clicked
$('#action').click(function() {
    // build up some html based on the input values
   var html = '<h1>' + $('#EmployeeName').val() + '</h1>'
   html += '<h2>' + $('#EmployeeSurname').val() + '</h2>'
   // set it in the textarea
   $('#result').html(html);
});
```

Should not be that hard to find documentation about online...

I set up a small fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jQ2Ya/